# An event has a 90.1 percent chance of happening. What is the probability of of triggering this event 70 times consecutively

Tags: probability, gambling

I have come up with a progressive betting strategy on a cryptocurrency gambling website for a random number generator game (between 0.01 and 99.99,) Basically if it rolls 9.9 or under, I win 10 times my original bet of 0.00000100 units, I have set to increase my bet by 16.5% every time I lose up until the maximum bet of .22 units

I have calculated I can lose about 70 times in a row before going bust. I didn't think i had anything to worry about until I lost 66 times in a row.

Should I be safe running this or change my strategy to something even more conservative? (It currently makes be about $30 an hr which I feel is a good risk/reward) Open to suggestions.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Well, $(.901)^{70}\approx 0.000677$ so this is quite unlikely. About five times as likely as being dealt a straight flush in  five cards.  Note:  not commenting on the betting strategy, just the probability question in the header.

Comment: This is a well-known gambling strategy, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system). The short of it is, if you actually want to make good bets, you want to look at the expected value of your bet and not the probability of losing.

Comment: Thankyou lulu and Alex, Very helpful